# Sitecore 7.5 MVC and HttpContext.Session.Timeout set to 1 min

Tags: asp.net-mvc, session, sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore7.5

I have the session timeout set to **20min** but when I try to access this value from action I'm getting **1min** instead.

Web.Config settings are:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20">

<authentication mode="None">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="20" />
</authentication>
```

In Global.asax.cs in Session_Start value of timeout is **20min**:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout
```

But in action in my controller is set to **1min**:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout 
HttpContext.Session.Timeout
```

I've found that when I remove `SitecoreHttpModule` which is of type (`Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule,Sitecore.Nexus`) from web.config the timeout works fine but I dont think I can remove it permanently.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule"/>
      <add type="Sitecore.Web.RewriteModule, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreRewriteModule"/>
      <!-- !!!REMOVED MODULE!!! <add type="Sitecore.Nexus.Web.HttpModule,Sitecore.Nexus" name="SitecoreHttpModule"/> -->
      <add type="Sitecore.Resources.Media.UploadWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreUploadWatcher"/>
      <add type="Sitecore.IO.XslWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreXslWatcher"/>
      <add type="Sitecore.IO.LayoutWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreLayoutWatcher"/>
      <add type="Sitecore.Configuration.ConfigWatcher, Sitecore.Kernel" name="SitecoreConfigWatcher"/>
      ...
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Is there any place I can configure this timeout for this module or there is any other way to set session timeout to desired value?

Comment: Do you have Sitecore Analytics enabled?

Comment: Yes, Sitecore Analytics are enabled.

Comment: I've tried to disable Analytics in Sitecore.Analytics.config

    <setting name="Analytics.Enabled" value="false" />

and timeout works fine, it's set to 20min. Any idea why?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every first request for a new user is considered as a possible bot request. That's why session timeout is set to 1 minute for those requests.

If the request is executed by the proper end user, there should be `VisitorIdentification` code on your page which in fact will cause another background call to the server and extend the session for the user.

Just add

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Extensions
...
@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()
```

to your layout .cshtml file.

Timeout will be set to 1 minute for the first request, but then automatically changed back to 20 (or whatever is configured), when Sitecore does the `VisitorIdentification` call.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in robots detection in Sitecore Analytics module. My browser is recognized as a bot and there are some settings about that in `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config` file:

```
 <!--  ANALYTICS ROBOTS SESSION TIMEOUT
        The ASP.NET Session Timeout for auto detected robots. 
        When the automatic robot detection identifies a session as being a robot, the ASP.NET
        Session Timeout is set to this value (in minutes).
        Default: 1
  -->
  <setting name="Analytics.Robots.SessionTimeout" value="1" />
```

The timeout is set to **1min** when bot is detected to save some mememory and not to keep session too long.

The timeout will be set to desired **20min** value when I either disable Analytics at all or disable `Analytics.AutoDetectBots` (in `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.config` file).

The proper solution for this is to clasify browser correctly (not as a bot).

Another post on this issue:

[Sitecore Analytics Robots SessionTimeout causing premature session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109919/sitecore-analytics-robots-sessiontimeout-causing-premature-session-timeout)

Comment: Just add `@using Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Extensions` ... `@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()` to your layout `.cshtml` file. Timeout will be set to 1 minute for the first request, but then automatically changed back to 20 (or whatever is configured), when Sitecore does the `VisitorIdentification` call.

Comment: The comment from @MarekMusielak solved the problem for me. As this is a different approach to the description in the solution, I would suggest you add this as a new answer.

Comment: @KevinBrechbühl answer added as you asked

Answer (score 1):

In Sitecore 7 there is now multiple places you have to specify the Session Timeout.

I would check these values in your Web.config.

```
<setting name="Authentication.ClientSessionTimeout" value="120" />
```

and

```
<forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="120" />
```

and then

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" ... timeout="120" />
```

More info here:

[Strange Timeout in Sitecore 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22228972/strange-timeout-in-sitecore-7)