# Why my httpsessionstate is loosing value?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

I'm dealing with the Sitecore app that stores some 'items' into the cart for users that are not authenticated (I guess they should not be) using code like this:

```cs
 this.Session["abc"]
```

Then once user arrive on cart page and wants to proceed than if he waits too long more than a minute than value in the session is lost !

Here is my `web.config` relevant settings:

I'm at the end of my ropes here and don't know what is cleaning my session?

```xml
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="20" sessionIDManagerType="Sitecore.FXM.SessionManagement.ConditionalSessionIdManager">
  <providers>
    <add name="mongo" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB.MongoSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.MongoDB" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
    <add name="mssql" type="Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql.SqlSessionStateProvider, Sitecore.SessionProvider.Sql" sessionType="Standard" connectionStringName="session" pollingInterval="2" compression="true" />
  </providers>
</sessionState>
```

and

```
<authentication mode="None">
  <forms name=".ASPXAUTH" cookieless="UseCookies" timeout="90" />
</authentication>
```

I guess you don't need to be authenticated to use the session?
And yes I did check the code ensuring that nothing nullifying my session.

Comment: Do you have `VisitorIdentification` in your layout? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465430/sitecore-8-session-times-out-at-1-minute

Comment: Thanks Marek, no I didn't have visitoridentification, how to add this to my layout?

Comment: @krul Sitecore.Analytics

Comment: Have it like this:<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Analytics" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <sc:VisitorIdentification id="VisitorIdentification1" runat="server" />

Comment: @krul are we talking about a production only issue ? Do you have a load balancer or this happens on your local ?

Comment: but still it complaints The type or namespace name 'VisitorIdentification' does not exist in the namespace 'Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls'

Comment: both local and production

Comment: @krul it is in the Sitecore.Analytics. No Idea why it complains. Maybe just an intelisense issue ?

Comment: Do you have `<system.web><pages><controls><add tagPrefix="sc" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="Sitecore.Analytics" />... other ...</controls>` in your web.config?

Comment: @MarekMusielak, I do

Comment: Check if Sitecore.Analytics is referenced from your project. Try to restart VS. sometimes it helps. Check whether you can load the page or whether it throws exception.

Comment: I'm considering alternative; using cache like this: Common.Helpers.CacheHelper.SetValue(Constants.CacheKeys.abc + this.Session.SessionID, ABC); What do you think about it?

Comment: @MarekMusielak and yes, I was missing sitecore.analytics dll in my project, thanks

Comment: Don't use cache as described in your comment. If your session is null, you will not have session id to retrieve item from cache.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96901/discussion-between-krul-and-marek-musielak).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue with 1 minute session timeout often happens when you don't have `VisitorIdentification` in your layout. Sitecore considers every new visitor as a potential crawling robot and tries not to use 20 minutes session if not necessary.

Make sure you have `VisitorIdentification` in your layouts. You can add it for Web Forms like that:

```xml
<%@ Import Namespace="Sitecore.Analytics" %>
<sc:VisitorIdentification runat="server" />
```

and for MVC like that:

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Extensions
@Html.Sitecore().VisitorIdentification()
```

If your Visual Studio still complains that it cannot find `VisitorIdentification` type in `Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls` namespace, check whether `Sitecore.Analytics` is referenced from your web project and if `Sitecore.Analytics` is registered in `<system.web><pages><controls>` in `web.config`:

```xml
<add tagPrefix="sc" namespace="Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="Sitecore.Analytics" />
```

---

**EDIT**:

Think about having thousands of sessions for robots and each of them can be pretty heavy in terms of RAM usage. If they are all kept for 20 minutes, they can kill the server easily. That's why Sitecore changes session timeout for every new user and sets it to 1 minute.

If Sitecore layout is configured properly and there is `VisitorIdentification` included, your browser will automatically execute another request to your server and your session timeout will be extended to default setting from `web.config` (e.g. 20 minutes)

Comment: Great answer, thanks - I was convinced there was a problem with the session state timeout , private or shared sesison etc, and it was just the lack of the visitor identification tag.